# How to avoid wildfly creating dependency for JNDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, jndi

I'm updating my wildfly from 10.01 to 17.01 and I noticed that some things changed.

I have an EJB which is in .ear A and I use the lookup for that EJB in .ear B. I use the lookup with the java:global/deployment/subdeployment... When I try to undeploy ear A the new version of wildfly is complaining because of the dependency but the older version was allowing me.

With the new version: 
WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("undeploy") failed - address - failure description: "WFLYCTL0441: Operation has resulted in failed or missing services 
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service ...\" (missing) dependents: [B.ear .....] 
WFLYCTL0448: 133 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed"
2019-09-11 16:50:50,828 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 646) WFLYSRV0007: Undeploy of deployment "A.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
"WFLYCTL0441: Operation has resulted in failed or missing services

Creating a custom binding in the wildfly domain.xml will allow me to undeploy ear A. Can someone tell me what changed that is causing this behaviour/ give me more resource where I can find more info about this? Is there any way I can keep the java:global.. without creating the custom binding but not considering the dependencies problem while undeploying?

Thank you!